# Can I find out when my initial blank slate install of macOS was?

Tags: macos, migration

It is possible I have migrated my data all the way from my first generation MacBook Pro (aluminium 17" from 2007, or maybe even earlier, 2003 PowerBook G4) through to current day. Moving between laptop every 5-7 years without a hitch. Ahh actually, 2012 retina MacBook Pro SSD failed a few weeks in, I wasn't anticipating that, so maybe that is how far back this lineage goes.

My question is, is there any way for me to find out when the last blank slate install of macOS was?

Maybe I can try find a timestamp in some super old logfile?

Comment: You can try looking at the creation dates of various system folders, your user folder, etc.

Comment: For me, it's my emails. I have some from my first home-based Mac in 2001. [POP not IMAP, so they's all under my control, migrated ever since] I was still running Mac OS 9 back then, didn't go to OS X until 2004, so I doubt any system files would have survived.

Comment: You can easily find old files (the oldest file I found in my home directory is dated Nov 26th, 2009) which may indicate since when you migrate data from one Mac to the next. Finding the date of the last clean install is be more challenging (and also somewhat open for debate: if you buy a new Mac and use Migration Assistant to transfer data from the old, does this count as a new install?).